# Caching Issue with PDF Reader

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, pdf, pdf-viewer

I have developed a pdf reader using **schwa/iOS-PDF-Reader API**. I am experiencing a caching problem, I supply my file path dynamically to the API, but the reader always brings up the first pdf file irrespective of the file path supplied.

Please help me out..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: No way to help this way. Please post relevant code.

Comment: The code has nothing to do,I think the particular API has got the issue. https://github.com/schwa/iOS-PDF-Reader

Comment: An example (code) of what you're doing is going to help everyone help you. If you think there is a bug in the library then you should post it on their issue tracker. And then come back here with the piece of code you think contains the bug if you can't solve it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can give all pdf paths into an array and then just pass array index path to your API.

Just try it i hope it will help for you.